# How to change opacity of overlaymaptypes?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do I change the overlayMapType opacity after I added to the map?

```
        var imgTypeOptions = {
            getTileUrl: function (coord, zoom) {                               
                return "myTile/" + f + ".png";        
            },
            tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
            name: "Imagen",
            opacity: .5 //This is Ok, the first time set the opacity
            //but i want to change the opacity later
        };

...
        var imgMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(imgTypeOptions);
...
    map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, imgMapType);
```

I want to be able to click a link "25%" and set the opacity of the added layer to 25%.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 3.28 you have to use the getter. Please try the following code:

```
map.overlayMapTypes.getAt(0).setOpacity(0.25)
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the ImageMapType api documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ImageMapType

Something like this should work.

```
map.overlayMapTypes[0].setOpacity(.25)
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2018, this is how you do with my working example.

I use open street map tile, sample

```
 z= zoom  
 x= coord.x  
 y= coord.y

https://tile.openstreetmap.org/10/261/380.png

https://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png
```

For tile, you should use ImageMapTypes,

then use

```
   map.overlayMapTypes.push(imageMapType);
```

or

```
   map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(
        0, new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(256, 256)));
```

to add new tile layer over the google base layer.

You can set opacity by :

```
 // for old api

 //map.overlayMapTypes[0].setOpacity(0.25);





   //for 3.28 api  (in 2018)

   map.overlayMapTypes.getAt(0).setOpacity(0.5);
```

[here is my working example jsfiddle, for overlay tile use ImageMapTypes](https://jsfiddle.net/hoogw/dtL147w2/1/)

another way of doing this:

[sample: use coordMapType instead of ImageMapTypes](https://jsfiddle.net/hoogw/m94qy82z/)